# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.8 Authentication credentials invalid

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

This piece of code is picked up from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_sending_simple_email.htm

```
//package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "ABC@gmail.com";

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "PQR@gmail.com";
        final String username = "NAME";
        final String password = "****";

        // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
        String host = "relay.jangosmtp.net";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        // Get the Session object.
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("Hello, this is sample for to check send "
                    + "email using JavaMailAPI ");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried getting hint from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358348/javamail-535-5-7-8-authentication-failed) link. But it seems to be using a slightly different method.

On running it with a debugger, exception seems to be coming from following code:

```
Transport.send(message);
```

Following is the stack trace:

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:58)
```

PS: I have checked the username and password. Also, 2 step sign in process is not enabled for the account from which I am trying to send mail.

Can someone please explain what could be the cause of authenticatio failure? Alternatively, if there is some other post which has already answered the query, please point me to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The server isn't happy with the username or password you're using.  You can probably guess the common reasons that might be the case, staring with you provided the wrong username or password.

The [JavaMail Session debugging output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) might provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

change  `String host = "relay.jangosmtp.net";`

to     `String host = "smtp.gmail.com";`

and  Port from `25`  to  `587`